# Java Exception column not found

Tags: java, jdbc

in this Code I try to retreive all the information that I need to make a RadarChart

In the first Query I retrieve the id of all the assets i have , After that and based on the assets ids , In the second query I retrieve the risks linked to each asset .

Finally I retrieve the value "calculated_risk" of each risk linked to a specified asset . same "mitigation_percent"

the problem I don't know if I'm doing it correctly or I have to change the way of developing what i want

because right now im facing a strange Exception :  java.sql.SQLException: Column 'risk_id' not found.

Even if the column risk_id exists
And when i do a test to return the values of id_assets it return only 2 values

Here my code :

```
 public ArrayList<risk> getGet_all_risk_for_radar_chart() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<risk> rr = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            DB_connection1 obj_DB_connection = new DB_connection1();
            connection = obj_DB_connection.get_connection();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select id from assets");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {

                risk r = new risk();
                r.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                rr.add(r);
                PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("select risk_id from risks_to_assets where asset_id = '" + r.getId() + "'");
                ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    r.setRisk_id(rs.getInt("risk_id"));
                    rr.add(r);
                    PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("select calculated_risk from risk_scoring where id = '" + r.getRisk_id() + "'");
                    ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                    while (rs2.next()) {
                        r.setCalculated_risk(rs2.getInt("calculated_risk"));
                        rr.add(r);
                        PreparedStatement ps3 = connection.prepareStatement("select mitigation_percent from mitigations where risk_id ='" + r.getRisk_id() + "'");
                        ResultSet rs3 = ps3.executeQuery();
                        while (rs3.next()) {
                            r.setMitigation_percent(rs3.getInt("mitigation_percent"));
                            rr.add(r);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rr;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `rs.getInt("risk_id")` should be `rs1.getInt("risk_id")`. However that isn't the real solution. You are currently performing multiple nested queries (basically l * (m * (n + 1) + 1) + 1), which is extremely inefficient. Please learn about joins and how you can execute this as one and only one query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks i didn't notice that , i dont i can do joins in my case because i will need the past values

Comment: That comment doesn't make sense. The way you're querying now using four levels of nested queries can be reduced to a single query and would have the same effect. You would need to add appropriate ordering and tracking values to reproduce the actions you take on each level, but nonetheless doing so would be more efficient than what you're doing now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Sorry for the last i didn't pay attention to what i write , I don't know how to do the joins in my case, because for example the first query returns several values ​​and I have to use these values ​​in the 2nd query . Is there a example or a tutorial that can be helpful ? and it is possible in my case ? so i learn about ! thank u

Comment: Any introductory text on SQL will cover joins (and if it doesn't, then throw it out).

Answer (score 0):

I did follow what Mark Rotteveel saids and now it works very well with SQL join
Here my new code :

```
 public static ArrayList<risk> getGet_all_risk_for_radar_chart2(){
        ArrayList<risk> rr = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection connection = null;
        try{

            DB_connection1 obj_DB_connection = new DB_connection1();
            connection = obj_DB_connection.get_connection();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select risks_to_assets.risk_id , asset_id , calculated_risk , mitigation_percent from risks_to_assets INNER JOIN risk_scoring ON risks_to_assets.risk_id=risk_scoring.id INNER JOIN mitigations ON risks_to_assets.risk_id=mitigations.risk_id  ");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                risk r = new risk();
                r.setRisk_id(rs.getInt("risk_id"));
                r.setId(rs.getInt("asset_id"));
                r.setCalculated_risk(rs.getInt("calculated_risk"));
                r.setMitigation_percent(rs.getInt("mitigation_percent"));
                rr.add(r);
            }

        
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();



        }
        return rr;
    }
```